# unify multiple tables with the same structure into one table in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have multiple tables with the same structure in a postgres database. I want to unify these tables into one table.

```
Table 1
         | a | b |
         ----|----
         | 1 | 2 |
Table 2 
         | a | b |
         ----|----
         | 3 | 4 | 
         | 5 | 6 |
Table 3
         | a | b |
         ----|----
         | 7 | 8 |

  Expected Output Table:
         | a | b |
         ----|----
         | 1 | 2 |
         | 3 | 4 | 
         | 5 | 6 |
         | 7 | 8 |
```

Can anyone help me in this issue?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by unify??? Do you mean that you want to collate the data from all the tables into one table?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @RhythemAggarwal: I edited my question. can you help me in that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be pretty simple. 
Check out the union Command. [Sql Union](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)
Basically you want to append all the data in one table. 
With the assumption that the tables are limited and you dont want any automation around that the easiest approach would be to build select union queries like below:

```
select a,b from table1
union
select a,b from table2
union
select a,b from table3
```

You can use the "insert into select" to create a new table with the outout of your result.